# Update nested data in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some data:

```
data: {
    series: [{
      name: 'my',
      data: [12,14],
    }],
},
```

I want to update this data from inside a function:

```
  myFunction: function(){
  axios.post('ajaxfile.php', {
    projectID: this.projectID,
    request: 1,
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    app.series.data=response.data;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

  },
```

But

```
app.series.data
```

doesn't seem to work. How can I access data -> series -> data?

Comment: try `this.series[0].data` if you just want to change data in that array(In VUE) else `data.series[0].data`